# Returning multiple include directories from a find-xxx.cmake file

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to add a custom find-xxx.cmake file to my cmake project in order to add an external library. The external project has some transitive dependencies not just for the linker, but for the precompiler too. I.e. I need to provide headers for protobuf and occi and a half dozen other small libraries in order to include the headers for the external project.

The relevant part of find-extlib.cmake:

```
function(MY_FIND_INCLUDE LIBNAME FILENAME SUFFIX)
find_path(${LIBNAME}_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES ${FILENAME}
    PATHS ${EXTLIB_POSSIBLE_DIRS}
    PATH_SUFFIXES ${SUFFIX} 
    )

if (${LIBNAME}_INCLUDE_DIR)
    MESSAGE_QUIETLY(EXTLIB_FIND_QUIETLY STATUS "Found ${${LIBNAME}_INCLUDE_DIR}")
elseif (EXTLIB_FIND_REQUIRED)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find extlib.")
else ()
    MESSAGE_QUIETLY(EXTLIB_FIND_QUIETLY WARNING "${LIBNAME} headers not found")
endif ()

mark_as_advanced(${LIBNAME}_INCLUDE_DIR)
endfunction ()

MY_FIND_INCLUDE(LIB1 header.h main/lib1)
if (LIB1_INCLUDE_DIR)
    set(EXTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS ${LIB1_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif ()
MY_FIND_INCLUDE(LIB2 lib2/lib2.h include)
if (LIB2_INCLUDE_DIR)
    set(EXTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS "${EXTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIB2_INCLUDE_DIR}")
endif ()
# etc, etc.
```

This returns a nice-looking list of all the include paths that I need to add. It looks just like my list of libraries, which I've made in a very similar fashion, and which seems to work.

In my `CMakeLists.txt`, I add:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${EXTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

The build fails, complaining that it can't find the headers in `LIB1` (or `LIB2`, etc). I can see in `MYLIB.dir/flags.make` on my Linux build that the list is not broken up. Where the flags *should* be:

```
-I path/to/lib1 -I path/to/lib2 ...
```

it instead lists

```
-I "path/to/lib1 path/to/lib2 ..."
```

Is this really the correct behaviour? Shouldn't I be able to provide multiple include directories for a single project? It would be overly tedious if I had to find all of these libraries separately. They come in the same configuration with this external library every time. It's always difficult to tell how Kitware actually intends for this stuff to be done... is there a different way I should be writing my Find module?

Comment: Just to add, now that I've gotten a bit more exposure to cmake, a custom find module is improved by adding the found libraries as import targets. [This](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#find-module-packages) page contains points to all of the relevant documentation, though it would be nice to see a blog post that explains things more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote each include directory separately.

Instead of:
`set(EXTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS "${EXTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIB2_INCLUDE_DIR}")`

Write:
`set(EXTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS "${EXTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}" "${LIB2_INCLUDE_DIR}")`

With the double quotes, you're including the whitespace in the string.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense in retrospect. I will stick with the list syntax in my answer, as you say, it's a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I can concatenate the directories using either a `;` instead of a space, or a little nicer, using `list(APPEND ...)`:

```
MY_FIND_INCLUDE(LIB1 header.h main/lib1)
if (LIB1_INCLUDE_DIR)
    list(APPEND EXTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS ${LIB1_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif ()
MY_FIND_INCLUDE(LIB2 lib2/lib2.h include)
if (LIB2_INCLUDE_DIR)
    list(APPEND EXTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS "${LIB2_INCLUDE_DIR}")
endif ()
```

Comment: Thumbs up on using `list(APPEND ...)` Makes the intention clearer.